# How to factory reset LG optimus L3 E405 from pc

Tags: factory-reset

I hav flashed a CWM recovery on my phone....
it shows this CWM recovery menu repeatedly,without booting into the system...
please tell me to factory reset it through pc as the factory reset option in the phone isnt wrking....

Comment: Does you PC detect it via `adb devices` or `fastboot devices`?

Answer (score -1):

Follow this steps, it will bring you phone back to life

http://www.hackmyandroid.com/how-unbrick-optimus-android-phone/1980

Comment: Answers that are nothing but a link somewhere else really aren't good answers. At the very least, what happens when that link stops working?